# shell cmd works but child_process.exec does not

Tags: node.js, shell, zip

`unzip -o /path/to/my.zip`

successfully creates a new directory with the inflated archive but

`require('child_process').exec('unzip -o /path/to/my.zip', function(err, stdout, stderr){…})`

doesn't create the new directory, even though there is no error and the stdout is the same as when I execute it directly in a shell. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And stderr is empty or ?

Comment: yes, stderr is also empty

Comment: What is node's current directory?